# Python: Finding and counting exact and approximate matches of words in txt file

Tags: python, match, counter

My program is close to doing what I want it to do, but I have one hangup: many of the keywords I'm trying to find might have symbols in the middle or might be misspelled. I would therefore like to count the words that are misspelled as keyword matches as if they word spelled correctly. For example, let's say my text says: "settlement settl#7*nt se##tl#ment ann&&ity annuity."

I want to count the times the .txt file has the keywords "settlement" and "annuity", but also words that begin with "sett" and end with "nt" as "settlement' and words that begin "ann" and end with "y" as annuity.

I've been able to count exact words and do pretty close to what I want it to do. But now I would like to do the approximate matches. I'm not even sure this is possible. Thanks.

```
out1 = open("seen.txt", "w")
out2 = open("missing.txt", "w")

def count_words_in_dir(dirpath, words, action=None):
    for filepath in glob.iglob(os.path.join("/Settlement", '*.txt')):
        with open(filepath) as f:
            data = f.read()
            for key, val in words.items():
                # print("key is " + key + "\n")
                ct = data.count(key)
                words[key] = ct
            if action:
                action(filepath, words)
            
                
                

def print_summary(filepath, words):
    for key, val in sorted(words.items()):
        whichout = out1 if val > 0 else out2
        print(filepath, file=whichout)
        print('{0}: {1}'.format(key, val), file=whichout)

filepath = sys.argv[1]
keys = ["annuity", "settlement"]
words = dict.fromkeys(keys, 0)

count_words_in_dir(filepath, words, action=print_summary)

out1.close()
out2.close()
```

Comment: Make you of https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith and https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For fuzzy matching you can use [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) module, install it one time through `pip install regex` command.

Through this regex module you can use any expression and through `{e<=2}` suffix you can specify number of errors that can appear in the word to match regular expression (one error is either substitution or insertion or deletion of one symbol). This is also called edit distance or [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

As an example I wrote my own function for counting words inside a given string. This function has `num_errors` param that specifies how many errors are alright for given word to match, I specified num_errors = 3, but you can set it to higher error rate, but don't set it to very high otherwise any word in text will match any reference word.

To split sentence into words I used `re.split()`.

[Try it online!](https://replit.com/@moytrage/StackOverflow67022770#main.py)

```
import regex as re
def count_words(text, words, *, num_errors = 3):
    we = ['(' + re.escape(e) + f'){{e<={num_errors}}}' for e in words]
    cnt = {e : 0 for e in words}
    for wt in re.split(r'[,.\s]+', text):
        for wre, wrt in zip(we, words):
            if re.fullmatch(wre, wt):
                cnt[wrt] += 1
                break
    return cnt

text = 'settlement settl#7*nt se##tl#ment ann&&ity annuity hello world.'
print(count_words(text, ['settlement', 'annuity']))
```

Output:

```
{'settlement': 3, 'annuity': 2}
```

---

As a faster alternative to regex module you can use [Levenshtein](https://pypi.org/project/python-Levenshtein/) module, install it once through `pip install python-Levenshtein` command.

This module implements only edit-distance (mentioned above) and should work much faster than regex module.

Same code as above but implemented using Levenshtein module is below:

[Try it online!](https://replit.com/@moytrage/StackOverflow67022770var2#main.py)

```
import Levenshtein, re
def count_words(text, words, *, num_errors = 3):
    cnt = {e : 0 for e in words}
    for wt in re.split(r'[,.\s]+', text):
        for wr in words:
            if Levenshtein.distance(wr, wt) <= num_errors:
                cnt[wr] += 1
                break
    return cnt

text = 'settlement settl#7*nt se##tl#ment ann&&ity annuity hello world.'
print(count_words(text, ['settlement', 'annuity']))
```

Output:

```
{'settlement': 3, 'annuity': 2}
```

---

As requested by OP I'm implementing 3rd algorithm that doesn't use any `re.split()` for splitting into words, but uses `re.finditer()` instead.

[Try it online!](https://replit.com/@moytrage/StackOverflow67022770var3#main.py)

```
import regex as re
def count_words(text, words, *, num_errors = 3):
    we = ['(' + re.escape(e) + f'){{e<={num_errors}}}' for e in words]
    cnt = {e : 0 for e in words}
    for wre, wrt in zip(we, words):
        cnt[wrt] += len(list(re.finditer(wre, text)))
    return cnt

text = 'settlement settl#7*nt se##tl#ment ann&&ity annuity hello world.'
print(count_words(text, ['settlement', 'annuity']))
```

Output:

```
{'settlement': 3, 'annuity': 2}
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you. But can you explain this a bit more? Ideally, I need to incorporate it into my code so that it counts from a directory of txt files, and then writes two new txt files with the file name and the count of words. Something like this:

/Users/seen.txt
settlement: 2
/Users/seen.txt
annuity: 1

Comment: @JohnD'Attoma If to incorporate my code into code that you provided in your question, then incorporation could look [like this](https://tio.run/##VU9BjsIwDLzzCotLE1RlD9yQ@AIXHlAF4oCh2FVi1OX13YQFQUeyD@PxjD089Cy8nqaAEY5yZ@1GSSF3xF2gZEoNXs8tPNkW/FFJeLsTRrtZQEGUBJF6rDIghlMvB0e1G8musu4ixGb5s0fVHm/IumyhWTn91ca@XCpGKg4yIJu3X5GlxoLPED@yiuDVwxaiS@iDsbNZwlxGX7@Yqm6hp6zmSbgrPrKxdr5H8fXdPKrin/86q2TYafoD), in this code `count_words()` is my function, and `action` you specify yourself, whatever you want. If you have some ready-made code you can send me your code and I'll incorporate my function inside.

Comment: Thanks again for the very quick reply. Based on your code, I'll try to figure it out. If I hit a dead end I'll likely send you some code.

Comment: this works pretty much exactly the way I need it to work. The only issue, and I assume it's an easy fix is that I need it to look for individual phrases, such as a "settlement payment". I assume that this has something to do with the re.split function, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: @JohnD'Attoma Yes, exactly, I used `re.split()` to split all text into words. You should replace this re.split with your algorithm of splitting into words. If you don't know how to split into necessary words, then now I'll try to implement another algorithm that doesn't need splitting.

Comment: @JohnD'Attoma Just implemented 3rd algorithm that you need, without re.split(), please put a look at my answer, just updated it now, look at very end of answer, there's algorithm without re.split(), it uses re.finditer() instead.Also don't forget about `num_errors` param, maybe value `3` is not enough for your case, just experiment.Also if you set this value too high then you'll have false positives,i.e. it will detect wrong words that shouldn't match.So try to start with 3 and if not all words are matched then increase it to 4,and measure again.To remind you - this value is number of mistakes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230963/discussion-between-john-dattoma-and-arty).

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks.